# Jinja2/Ansible Comparing HostVars Values In A Template

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to compare the values of 2 inventory file based hosts' `hostvars` magic variables in an Ansible Jinja Template. The asking is to basicallyensure that an item is included in the resulting template output, only if the IP addresses of 2 hosts in the inventory are not identical.

I have tried doing this:

```
{%if {{hostvars[‘CoolServer-1’][‘ansible_default_ipv4’][‘address’]}} != {{hostvars[‘Coolserver2-1’][‘ansible_default_ipv4’][‘address’]}} %}
df -h
{% endif %}
```

However, that fails and Jinja/Ansible freaks out. Is there a way I can accomplish what I am trying to do with comparing `hostvars` values in Jinja with Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `{{` inside `{% if`.

Try with:

```
{% if hostvars['CoolServer-1']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] != hostvars['Coolserver2-1']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] %}
df -h
{% endif %}
```

P.S. and check your single quotes (`‘`), they seem strange and different from `'`.

Comment: Thanks! the `{{` were exactly the issue